# Rails app accidentally installed in root folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I accidentally created a Rails app in my root directory. I ran the following command and got an error:

```
rails new test_app
Can't initialize a new Rails application within the directory of another, please change to a non-Rails directory first.
```

So I tried running

```
bundle exec rails server
```

and it looks like the server is listening on port 3000.

How do I remove this app from my root directory?

Comment: Just delete the folder containing the app, I believe.

Answer (score 3):

Just delete the folder or you can execute this command

```
rm -rf test_app
```

Answer (score 1):

Hoping you're on *nix based system.

1. Stop the running server using:

   ```
   kill -9 $(lsof -t -i :3000)
   ```
2. Change working directory to root using:

   ```
   cd /
   ```

   or wherever you're defining your root as.
3. Remove the accidentally created Rails application directory using:

   ```
   rm -fr rails_project_in_root_dir
   ```

   where `rails_project_in_root_dir` is the Rails application directory in  your root directory.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm not sure how it got installed in the root directory, but I ended up just manually deleting all the folders and files that get created when you run

```
rails new app
```

Here's where I found the list of files:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

That ended up resolving the issue. Thanks for the help guys.